# Best Practice on design and usage of data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My question is related to a [more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3077866/1311956) on Haskell program design. But I would like to focus on a specific use case.

I defined a data type (e.g. `Foo`), and used it in a function (e.g. `f`) through pattern matching. Later, I realized that the type (`Foo`) requires some additional field to support new functionalities. However, adding the field would change how the type can be used; i.e. the existing functions depending on the type could be affected. Adding new functionalities to existing code, however unappealing, is hard to avoid. I am wondering what are the best practices at the Haskell language level to minimize the impact of such kind of modifications.

For example, the existing code is:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  vv :: [Int]
}

f :: Foo -> Int
f (Foo v) = sum v
```

The function `f` will be syntax wrong if I add another field to `Foo`:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  vv :: [Int]
  uu :: [Int]
}
```

However, if I had defined function `f` as the following in the first place:

```
f :: Foo -> Int
f foo = sum $ vv foo
```

, then even with the modification on `Foo`, `f` would still be correct.

Comment: This is known as the expression problem in computer science.

Answer (score 6):

Lenses solve this problem well.  Just define a lens that points to the field of interest:

```
import Control.Lens

newtype Foo = Foo [Int]

v :: Lens' Foo [Int]
v k (Foo x) = fmap Foo (k x)
```

You can use this lens as a getter:

```
view v :: Foo -> [Int]
```

... a setter:

```
set v :: [Int] -> Foo -> Foo
```

... and a mapper:

```
over v :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Foo -> Foo
```

The best part is that if you later change your data type's internal representation, all you have to do is change the implementation of `v` to point to the new location of the field of interest.  If your downstream users only used the lens to interact with your `Foo` then you won't break backwards compatibility.

Comment: Do you have a sense of what amount of overhead (if any) is introduced if you use `lens` to access all record fields, instead of using the field accessors directly?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I believe lens is fast and light-weight, but I haven't benchmarked it.  I know that Edward does all kinds of tricks to ensure they compile to ridiculously fast code and when I asked him how fast the library was he said it was really fast and I took his word for it.

Comment: Although lenses are a great idea for complicated datastructures, I think they're overkill for simple use cases, introducing extra boilerplate and conceptual complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for processing types that might get new fields added that you want to ignore in existing code is indeed to use record selectors as you've done.

I would say that you should always define any type that might change using record notation, and you should never pattern match on a type defined with record notation using the first style with positional arguments.

Another way of expressing the above code is:

```
f :: Foo -> Int
f (Foo { vv = v }) = sum v
```

This is arguably more elegant, and it also works better in the case where `Foo` has multiple data constructors.

Comment: Also, with the `NamedFieldPuns` extension you could write `f (Foo { vv }) = sum vv` and with the `RecordWildCards` extension you could write `f (Foo { .. }) = sum vv`.

Comment: Don't do the latter or your code will break if someone adds `sum` to the record :-)

There are good use cases for `RecordWildCards` (and I work for the company that originally implemented them to make a DSL work better) but a short function like this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `f` function is so simple that perhaps the easiest answer would be to write it in point-free style using composition:

```
f' :: Foo -> Int
f' = sum . vv
```

If your function needs more than one field from the `Foo` value, the above wouldn't work. But we could employ the `Applicative` instance for `(->)` and do the following trick:

```
import Control.Applicative

data Foo2 = Foo2 {
    vv' :: [Int]
  , uu' :: [Int]
  }

f2 :: Foo2 -> Int
f2 = sum . liftA2 (++) vv' uu'
```

For functions, `liftA2` applies an input argument to two functions and then combines the results in another function, `(++)` in this case. But perhaps this borders on the obscure.